# Is it worthy to use XMPP pubsub for feeds?

Tags: facebook, twitter, xmpp, feed, publish-subscribe

I have read [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/rabble/beyond-rest-building-data-services-with-xmpp-pubsub) about why using XMPP and pubsub for retrieving data services which are often updated (such as feeds). I got immediately convinced about the push feature of pubsub in compassion to polling rest requests.

However, I tried to search for data apis deployed with XMPP pusub and I could not find much (just [buddycloud](https://buddycloud.org/wiki/XMPP_XEP) and [OneSocialWeb](http://onesocialweb.org/developers-xmpp.html) - where there is no more active development).

As far as I understood, [Facebook is using HTTP Etags](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/627/) and Twitter is using [http push](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/connecting), even if I found one [official blog post](http://blog.twitter.com/2008/07/twitter-and-xmpp-drinking-from-fire.html) (and no more) where twitter mentioned about having a xmpp feed.

Is there any reason why those and other platforms serving feeds are not favoring XMPP pubsub? Or perhaps are they just offering XMPP pub-sub alternatives through special arrangements?

The best answer I have seen so far has been [this blog post](http://www.defuze.org/archives/163-is-xmpp-for-the-web-ready.html), which is dated from the beginning of 2009. Has nothing changed since then?

Comment: You might want to check out https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/. It has the push functionality you are looking with a much simplified protocol.

Comment: I read about it as well, but I also have not seen many updates there (last code change is from 2011) and I did not find any big platforms using it